# Поиск в массиве php

Tags: массивы, php

Доброй ночи господа, есть несколько массивов в котором значения разные

Вот один из них,

```
$ar1 = Array(
    "id" => "7777",
    "product_id" => "777",
    "meta_key" => "primer",
    "meta_value" => "1",
    "custom" => "0"
);
```

Как мне найти значение

```
"meta_value"
```

если я знаю

```
"meta_key" => "primer"
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К примеру, объединить все массивы в один:

```
$glob = array($ar1, $ar2);
foreach($glob as $item) {
  if($item['meta_key'] === "primer") {
    echo $item['meta_value'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо!